# What happens to a Microsoft account if a custom domain expires?

Tags: onedrive, domain-name, microsoft-account

My family uses Microsoft accounts to logon to our PCs, OneDrive, etc. All of our accounts belong to a custom domain (*@something.dk) that I have purchased. What happens to our Microsoft accounts (and access to our assets on OneDrive) if I forget to pay for domain renewal, and it therefore expires?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you lose access to your e-mail address without any other recovery options, you might be hosed. If you did, however, set up alternate e-mail addresses or mobile phones, you can use the "Can't access your account?" link on any Microsoft sign-in page to start a process by which you can log in. From there, you can use the "Manage your account aliases" page to add another e-mail address and make it your primary one. After that's done, you can dissociate the original address.

It is conceivable that you could provide enough personal details from the "I don't have any of these" account recovery option. These data are things like birth date, past passwords, location, credit cards, etc. If so, you can get in and perform the above. If you can't get enough information together, you'll be subjected to a few days of delay.

So, make sure you keep your recovery options up to date. If you do that, you'll be able to get back in. There is still the danger, however, of the new domain owner being able to receive your e-mails and reset your password and information, so don't let your domain expire before the month-long e-mail dissociation reversal window closes.

Sources: [Ask Leo](https://askleo.com/how-do-i-get-into-my-hotmailoutlook-com-account-if-i-dont-have-the-recovery-phone-or-email-any-more/), [Microsoft how-to](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-10/change-the-email-for-your-microsoft-account)

Answer (score -1):

If somebody else renews the account and then setup their DNS and mail server

And if they have catch all email account they would start getting your emails

So even if Microsoft doesn't realize that you do not own the domain you would no longer receive new emails 
You might still be able to login

But if the new owner realizes that there is already a Microsoft account for the same once they are getting those emails they might be able to recover or reset your account and lock you out of it

***Source*** : personal experience I bought a domain recently and after i setup catch all I started getting emails of the previous owner

Comment: a Microsoft account doesn't necessarily imply an email (Outlook.com) account.  What you said about email is true, but that is regardless of having a MS account, you lose your domain you also lose email to that domain - period.   The last paragraph is the truly important part, if they catch-all email on your former domain, then they may be able to use "lost my password" and "send recovery via email" to gain access to ANY account (not just MS) that you signed up for with that email address.  Morale of the story :: protect your domain assets, auto-renew is your friend.